# I have changed signature in avrdude but not able to load bootloader in atmega328-PU with UNO

Tags: arduino

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9514
avrdude: Expected signature for ATmega328P is 1E 95 0F
         Double check chip, or use -F to override this check.

Answer (score 0):

If the bootloader has been compiled for ATmega328P it may not work as expected on 328PB (I personally experience issues on application code).

Also the 328PB is a quite recent chip and may not be completely supported by avrdude [ref](http://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?48237)